# Is there a way to use private git repository with Berkshelf

Tags: git, chef-infra, berkshelf

I created a cookbook named `foo`, and want to use with `Berkshelf`.

I wrote like this in `Berksfile`:

```
cookbook 'foo', git: 'https://bitbucket.org/ironsand/cookbook-foo.git'
```

Then vendor the cookbook to `cookbooks` directory, but it failed with error like this:

```
berks vendor cookbooks
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'foo' from https://bitbucket.org/ironsand/cookbook-foo.git (at master)
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org':
```

How can I tell ssh username and key to `Berkshelf`?
Of course my user have right to access the git repository.

Comment: If you want to use the "ssh username and key", have you tried specifying an [SSH URL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-RepositoryURLformatsbyconnectionprotocol) ?

Comment: I want to know how to specify the ssh URL with `berks` command.

Comment: From bershelf documentation: "If you need to reference a private Github repository then you should use the :git location with the ssh protocol." So see @Joe link in SSH URL...

Comment: Oh, now I got what @Joe means, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use ssh authentication with your git provider, you need to use an SSH URL.  Try something like this:

```
cookbook 'foo', git: 'git@bitbucket.org/ironsand/cookbook-foo.git'
```

That will use your SSH key to authenticate.