# Berkshelf vendoring of cookbook on private Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant, bitbucket, berkshelf

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get Berkshelf to download a company cookbook from our private BitBucket (git) repository. This is on a Windows 8.1 host.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214497/is-there-a-way-to-use-private-git-repository-with-berkshelf) and have attempted what was described in the answer. I also played around with the instructions Atlassian advises about [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket;jsessionid=153441FCABF0D637B6E20018F2BEBB1A.node1) and especially on their page about [ssh for multiple identities](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168).

- I have generated a public key with puttygen and added it as a deployment key to Bitbucket repo.
- I saved the private key in `C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh\mykey.ppk`.
- I added `C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh\config` with the following contents:

  `Host mycompany
  HostName bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.ppk`
- I try to include the cookbook in berksfile like this:

  `cookbook 'mycookbook', git: "git@mycompany:myteam/mycookbook.git", protocol: :ssh`

When I run `$ berks install -d` I get:

```
Fetching 'mycookbook' from git@mycompany:myteam/mycookbook.git (at master)
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/mykey.ppk':
Git error: command `git clone git@mycompany:myteam/mycookbook.git "C:/Users/MyUser/.berkshelf/.cache/git/6d5b957656d1bda26bf05aea558176c86db263f2" --bare --no
-hardlinks` failed. If this error persists, try removing the cache directory at 'C:/Users/MyUser/.berkshelf/.cache/git/6d5b957656d1bda26bf05aea558176c86db263f2'.Output from the command:

Cloning into bare repository 'C:/Users/MyUser/.berkshelf/.cache/git/6d5b957656d1bda26bf05aea558176c86db263f2'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Do I have to replace 'git' in front of the @ with my user name?

Also - note that it asks me for the passphrase of the ppk, which I just confirm with `enter' as I left it blank. But shouldn't it just read it without prompting for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

- Make sure that the environment variable `HOME` is set to `C:\Users\MyUser` when you are running the `berks` command.
- Use a full path for the private key

  ```
  Host mycompany
  HostName bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile /C/User/MyUser/.ssh/mykey.ppk
  ```
- try and use rsa keys instead of private putty keys (ppk)

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa
  ```

(reference the *private* key in `IdentityFile`: the `id_rsa` one, add the public one to the BitBucket repo)

The [OP phpphil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4586767/phpphil) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519883/berkshelf-vendoring-of-cookbook-on-private-bitbucket-repository/30522261#comment49120987_30522261):

> Turned out the last point fixed it - I used the puttygen user interface to export the key **`Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key`** as `mykey.pub`, then simply changed the config to `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pub`.
>   It worked with the relative path as well.

Comment: Genius! Turned out the last point fixed it - I used the puttygen user interface to export the key `Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key` as `mykey.pub`, then simply changed the config to `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.ppk`. It worked with the relative path as well. Thanks so much, you saved my day :)

Comment: @phpPhil Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks for that. Little correction as I can't edit my comment... it should read `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pub`. **pub** instead of ppk.